# Ruby name of method that not called from another method by using dot

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby by using TDD (Test Driven Development). In `Rspec` code, I often see:

```
it "return the sum of two different arugments" do
      calc = Calculator.new
      expect(calc.add(1,2)).to eq(3)
 end
```

Often, in other languages, the last command often would be written as `eq (expect(calc(1,2)), 3)` or `expect(calc.add(1,2)).eq(3)`.

But in the example, there is nothing connecting the first phrase `expect(calc.add(1,2))` and second phrase `eq(3)`.

So in Ruby, what is the name of this grammar?

Comment: It's called *poetry mode.*

Comment: @DigitalRoss wow thanks for `poetry mode`.

Comment: Yeah, @sawa should update his answer to note that it's called *poetry mode.*   It's used a lot for DSL code. You can't directly do method chaining in poetry mode so what I do for fun is things like this: instead of, say, `IO.readlines(f).map { whatever }` I instead write `(IO.readlines f).map { whatever }`.  Tho if u do, your team members will probably complain about your style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply is that a pair of parentheses around the arguments can be omitted.

```
expect(calc.add(1, 2)).to eq(3)
```

is syntax sugared form of:

```
expect(calc.add(1, 2)).to(eq(3))
```

That is, `eq(3)` is the argument of the method `to`.

According to @DigitalRoss, it seems to be called *poetry mode*.

Comment: Is the omission of parentheses sugar, or is their inclusion unnecessary (except when needed to eliminate ambiguity)?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby favor brevity and shortcuts, also known as sugar. One of these is omitting parenthesis.

You can also omit other parens (other than `expect` which needs them), e.g. you can also do:

```
expect(calc.add 1,2).to eq 1
```

instead of the longer

```
expect(calc.add(1, 2)).to(eq(3))
```

Comment: Michael, I don't see how this adds to @sawa's earlier solution (except for `eq 1` vs `eq(1)`, which is minor).